# How to make my pytorch model to behave differently in training and inference phase?

Tags: pytorch

I'm writing a transformer-like pytorch model which use a cache to speed up calculations in the inference phase. But I don't want to use this feature during training. Is there a way to allow me to tell the model how to behave differently after `model.train()` and `model.eval()`?

I have tried searching for tutorials but got no results. I can use `if _ else _` expression to skip this issue for now, but I hope there is a more formal solution, which can work with the two built-in pytorch funcrions above.

Comment: What is wrong with using if/else logic? Why is that not a "formal" solution? Using if/else around train/eval is standard practice. Calling `model.train()` and model.eval()` simply changes the `model.training` boolean flag. Standard logic would generally be `if self.training: ..., else: ...`